# Weird query in mysql optimizer

Tags: mysql, explain, mysql-slow-query-log

I'm working with mysql 5.5.52 on a Debian 8 machine and sometimes we have a slow query (>3s) that usually spends 0.1s. I've started with the explain command to find what is happening.

This is the query and the explain info

```
explain
SELECT
   `box`.`message_id` ID
 , `messages`.`tipo`
 , `messages`.`text`
 , TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), `messages`.`date`)) `date`
FROM (`box`)
INNER JOIN `messages` ON `messages`.`id` = `box`.`message_id`
WHERE `box`.`user_id` = '1010231' AND `box`.`deleted` = 0 
    AND `messages`.`deleted` = 0 
    AND `messages`.`date` + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE > NOW()
ORDER BY `messages`.`id` ASC LIMIT 100;


id| select_type| table  | type |  possible_keys   | key   | key_len| ref          | rows | Extra    
 1|SIMPLE      |box     |ref   |user_id,message_id|user_id|       4|const         | 2200 |Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort   
 1|SIMPLE      |messages|eq_ref|PRIMARY           |PRIMARY|       4|box.message_id|    1 |Using where
```

I know that temporary table and filesort are a bad thing, and I suppose that the problem is that order key doesn't belong to the first table in the query (box) and changing it to box.message_id, the explain info is

> id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
>
> 1  SIMPLE  box index   user_id,message_id  message_id  4       443 Using where
>
> 1  SIMPLE  messages    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   box.message_id  1   Using where

It looks better, but I don't understand why it's using the message_id index, and worst, now the query takes 1.5s instead of initial 0.1s

Edit:

Forcing the query to use user_id index, I get the same result (0.1s) as the initial query but without the temporary

```
explain
SELECT
   `box`.`message_id` ID
 , `messages`.`tipo`
 , `messages`.`text`
 , TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), `messages`.`date`)) `date`
FROM (`box` use index(user_id) )
INNER JOIN `messages` ON `messages`.`id` = `box`.`message_id`
WHERE `box`.`user_id` = '1010231' AND `box`.`deleted` = 0 
    AND `messages`.`deleted` = 0 
    AND `messages`.`date` + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE > NOW()
ORDER BY `box`.`message_id` ASC LIMIT 100;

id| select_type| table  | type |  possible_keys   | key   | key_len| ref          | rows | Extra    
 1|SIMPLE      |box     |ref   |user_id,message_id|user_id|       4|const         | 2200 |Using where; Using filesort   
 1|SIMPLE      |messages|eq_ref|PRIMARY           |PRIMARY|       4|box.message_id|    1 |Using where
```

I think that skipping temporary is better solution than the initial query, next step is check combined index as ysth recommends.

Comment: Could you show the query that produced the second explain?

Comment: Ah, you mean you changed the order by from message.id to box.message_id?

Comment: `AND \`messages\`.\`date\` + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE > NOW()` -> `AND \`messages\`.\`date\` > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE`. Do not do any transformation on columns when it is not necessary. (This may not be an issue in this case, but just an FYI).

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the two tables.

Comment: any more progress on this?

Comment: @ysth I'm bussy with a more urgent issue, I'm using the "use index" solution untill I'll can check the combined index one, I want to be sure before changing database.

Comment: ah, so maybe the slow queries were when it decided to use the message_id index and the fast ones when it decided to use the user_id index?  I don't know why the difference in using temporary or not; that is very strange.

Comment: Try this:  Add to `messages`:  `INDEX(deleted, date)`.

Answer (score 0):

it is not a good idea to calculate on fieldvalues to compare. then you get a FULL TABLE SCAN. MySQL must do it for each ROW before it can check the condition. Its better to do it on the constant piece of condition. Then MySQL can use a Index (if there one on this field)

**change from**

```
AND messages.date + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE > NOW()
```

*to*

```
AND messages.date  > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

Comment: But he isn't getting a full table scan; date is not a index here.

Comment: I know that calculations don't work with index, but that field (date) is not indexed and in the modified query, optimizer is using index, but for me the wrong one (message_id)

Comment: Well, add `INDEX(user_id, deleted, date)` -- then the tmp+filesort + table scan will go away.

Comment: @RickJames user_id is in a different table.  If it could be added to messages, that would probably be an ideal index, but I'm guessing it can't.

Comment: Messages table can not contain user_id because some messages are for groups or all users, but  INDEX(user_id, deleted, date) it's ok for box table, but I prefer to avoid using many specific index if it's possible. As ysth said "that might also end up worse. Depends on your exact data."

Answer (score 0):

Temporary and file sort are *not* bad here; they are needed because using the best index (user_id) doesn't naturally produce records sorted in the order you ask for.

It's possible you might do better having a combined user_id,message_id index, but that might also end up worse.  Depends on your exact data.

It isn't clear to me if you are seeing longer queries for certain user id's or the same user id sometimes taking much longer.

Update: it seems likely that having a combined index and changing order by to box.user_id,box.message_id will solve your problem, at least for users that don't have a large number of deleted messages.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Slow queries are "random", if I execute the same query multiple times, usually works ok, but sometimes I have a slow query. The query is not the problem, but I've started trying to optimize it.

Comment: I don't understand why it's using message_id as index only when I use it to order by, with message.id order by optimizer uses user_id, it's like order by index takes precedence over where index.

Comment: It has to guess whether it is going to get your 100 results fastest by reading through box in order by message id or reading through just one users messages.  If you remove the date and deleted conditions, I bet it is right.